# Отследить прокрутку

Tags: javascript, html

мне необходимо отследить на каком из section я нахожусь. То есть вот долистал я до 3 section и мне надо получить id
Думал `this` цепанет, но посмотрел через `console.log()`, он берет все section со страницы.

```
    <section id='banners'>
1
</section>
<section id='2'>
2
</section>
<section id='3'>
3
</section>
<section id='4'>
4
</section>
<section id='5'>
5
</section>
<section id='6'>
6
</section>
<section id='7'>
7
</section>
```

JS:

```
$("#banners .video").css("opacity", "1");
        $(window).scroll( function(){
            $('.content_wrap section').each( function(i){
                var bottom_of_object = $(this).position().top + $(this).outerHeight()*0.5;
                var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();

                var blOneHeight = $("#banners").height()*0.04; //Высота блока
                var blOneOuterHeight = $(window).scrollTop();

                if (blOneOuterHeight > blOneHeight) {
                    if( bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object ){
                        $(this).find(".video").css("opacity", "1");
                        $("#banners .video").css("opacity", "0");
                        if ($("#banners .video").css("opacity") == '0') {
                            $("#banners .video").css("display", "none");
                        }
                    } else {
                        $(this).find(".video").css("opacity", "0");
                    }
                } else {
                    $(this).find(".video").css("opacity", "0");
                    $("#banners .video").fadeIn(1,function(){
                        $('#banners .video').css("display", "block");
                        $('#banners .video').css("opacity", "1");
                    });
                }
            }); 
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var scrollHandle = function() {
 var top = $(window).scrollTop();
 var section = $('section').map(function() {
      if ($(this).offset().top <= top) return this
  });
  
  if(section.length) {
    section = section[section.length - 1];
    $(".out").text(section.id);
  }
}
$(window).on('scroll resize', scrollHandle).trigger('scroll');
```

```css
section {
  min-height: 100vh;
}
.out {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  position: fixed;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  right: 15px;
  top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/8.0.0/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="out"></div>
<section id='banners'>
banners
</section>
<section id='2'>
2
</section>
<section id='3'>
3
</section>
<section id='4'>
4
</section>
<section id='5'>
5
</section>
<section id='6'>
6
</section>
<section id='7'>
7
</section>
```

Comment: Почему то берет последний section

Comment: В смысле? http://take.ms/hP2eE В красной плашке отображается id той секции, которую вы просматриваете.